# How do I generate a pdf-file from a binary file in R?

Tags: r, pdf, base64, binaryfiles

I am using R, version 3.3.2.. I have base64 encoded binary file. Here is just a part of the content:

```
list(structure(list("584959666b2e5f32bc43fad1", "584959666b2e5f32bc43fad1.pdf", 
    91572L, "JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOEKMSAwIG9iago8PAovUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIKL05hbWVzIDI2IDAgUgovUGFnZUxheW91dC9PbmVDb2x1bW4KL01ldGFkYXRhIDI4IDAgUgovVHlwZS9DYXRhbG9nCi9PdXRwdXRJbnRlbnRzWwo8PAovT3V0cHV0Q29uZGl0aW9uKCkKL091dHB1dENvbmRpdGlvbklkZW50aWZpZXIoQ3VzdG9tKQovUmVnaXN0cnlOYW1lKCkKL0luZm8oc1JHQiBJRUM2MTk2Ni0yLjEpCi9UeXBlL091dHB1dEludGVudAovRGVzdE91dHB1dFByb2ZpbGUgMyAwIFIKL1MvR1RTX1BERkExCj4+Cl0KL1ZpZXdlclByZWZlcmVuY2VzIDQgMCBSCi9QYWdlTW9kZS9Vc2VOb25lCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9Db3VudCAxCi9LaWRzWzUgMCBSXQovVHlwZS9QYWdlcwo+PgplbmRvYmoKMyAwIG9iago8PAovTiAzCi9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUKL0xlbmd0aCAyNTM3Cj4+CnN0cmVhbQp4Xp2WZ1RT2RbHz703vVCSEDqE3qS3ANJ7k15FKUmAUAIGAojYEFGBEUVEmg0ZFHDA0aHIWBHFwoCgYHeCDCLqOFgQFctL5K3RN++9WTPz/3DPb+1y7zl777PWBYDk5cflZcBSAKTzsvnBni6MyKhoBnYQwAAPMMAUgHhWVqZ/iEcoEMnb3ZWRJQoC/6HXYwASr9cMvQIZDPD3JM3K5GcDAAWK2JzNyWKJuEjEabnZmWL7jIhpCalihlFi5os2KGI5MSct8KLPMQvsJGZ2Oo8tYvGeM9npbDH3iXhzjoAjYsRPxMU5XE6uiK+LWDNNkM4V8RtxbjonPgsAFElsz+awkkVsImISPzTYVcSLAcCRkr7ihK84m5OXLT4U42/q37WgiGvLEBXZytTGysrQzMgUfNGfOv+ixL1doJdBn3sG0Qe+2P5XXEYDAMxZUW22fbEl1ADQtREAudtfbJr7AJAU9a1zaKGHn0X/s8P+pYC/oK++ZySez9/Lw3DjJMYL0rIZ4rqxMtIyBHxGVmY8i8Mw/OMQ/+PEr/TVPhYFcxI5fA5PlBEumjIuL4nhmsFjc7O5GTwGl/f/mvgP0/6ghbkWidr4EdBijYDUEA0gvw4AFJUIkJg9Ig/0e9/88OFAfPMiVKcW5v6zoP9+K1wufmRxkz7nuQaHMlgCfs6CT3wtARoQgCSgAXmgAjSALjAEZsAa2AEn4A58QAAIBVFgOWCBZJAO+CAXFID1oBiUgm1gJ6gFe0EjaAZt4CjoAifAWXABXAFXwSi4A4RgEjwBM+A1mIcgCAuRISokD6lCWpABZAYxIQfIHfKDgqEoKA5KgniQACqANkClUAVUC+2HmqHvoePQWegSNAzdgsahaegF9A5GYBJMg5VhbdgYZsLOsC8cCi+Dk+AVcD5cBG+Fq+EG+DDcCZ+Fr8CjsBB+As8iACEidEQNMUSYiCsSgEQjiQgfWYOUIFVIA9KG9CD9yDVEiDxF3qIwKCqKgTJE2aG8UGEoFmoFag2qDFWLOoTqRPWhrqHGUTOoj2gyWgltgLZFe6Mj0UnoXHQxugrdhO5An0ePoifRrzEYDB2jg7HGeGGiMCmYVZgyzG5MO+YMZhgzgZnFYrHyWAOsPTYAG4/NxhZja7CHsaexI9hJ7BscEaeKM8N54KJxPFwhrgrXgjuFG8FN4ebxUngtvC0+AM/Gr8SX4xvxPfgh/CR+niBN0CHYE0IJKYT1hGpCG+E84S7hJZFIVCfaEIOIXOI6YjXxCPEicZz4lkQh6ZNcSTEkAWkr6SDpDOkW6SWZTNYmO5GjydnkreRm8jnyffIbCaqEkYS3BFtirUSdRKfEiMQzSbyklqSz5HLJfMkqyWOSQ5JPpfBS2lKuUvFSa6TqpI5L3ZCalaZKm0oHSKdLl0m3SF+SfkTBUrQp7hQ2pYhygHKOMkFFqBpUVyqLuoHaSD1PnaRhaDo0b1oKrZT2HW2QNiNDkbGQCZfJk6mTOSkjpCN0bbo3PY1eTj9KH6O/k1WWdZblyG6RbZMdkZ2TU5RzkuPIlci1y43KvZNnyLvLp8pvl++Sv6eAUtBXCFLIVdijcF7hqSJN0U6RpViieFTxthKspK8UrLRK6YDSgNKssoqyp3Kmco3yOeWnKnQVJ5UUlUqVUyrTqlRVB1WuaqXqadXHDBmGMyONUc3oY8yoKal5qQnU9qsNqs2r66iHqReqt6vf0yBoMDUSNSo1ejVmNFU1/TULNFs1b2vhtZhayVq7tPq15rR1tCO0N2l3aT/SkdPx1snXadW5q0vWddRdoduge10Po8fUS9XbrXdVH9a31E/Wr9MfMoANrAy4BrsNhhehF9ks4i1qWHTDkGTobJhj2Go4bkQ38jMqNOoyemasaRxtvN243/ijiaVJmkmjyR1TiqmPaaFpj+kLM30zllmd2XVzsrmH+VrzbvPnFgYWHIs9FjctqZb+lpssey0/WFlb8a3arKatNa3jrOutbzBpzEBmGfOiDdrGxWatzQmbt7ZWttm2R21/szO0S7VrsXu0WGcxZ3Hj4gl7dft4+/32QgeGQ5zDPgeho5pjvGOD4wMnDSe2U5PTlLOec4rzYednLiYufJcOlzlXW9fVrmfcEDdPtxK3QXeKe5h7rft9D3WPJI9WjxlPS89Vnme80F6+Xtu9bngre7O8m71nfKx9Vvv0+ZJ8Q3xrfR/46fvx/Xr8YX8f/x3+d5doLeEt6QoAAd4BOwLuBeoErgj8MQgTFBhUF/Qw2DS4ILg/hBoSG9IS8jrUJbQ89E6YbpggrDdcMjwmvDl8LsItoiJCGGkcuTrySpRCFDeqOxobHR7dFD271H3pzqWTMZYxxTFjy3SW5S27tFxhedryk7GSsfGxx+LQcRFxLXHv4wPiG+JnE7wT6hNmWK6sXawnbCd2JXuaY8+p4Ewl2idWJD5Ksk/akTSd7JhclfyU68qt5T5P8UrZmzKXGpB6MPVTWkRaezouPS79OI/CS+X1Zahk5GUMZxpkFmcKV9iu2Llihu/Lb8qCspZldWfTRD9TAwJdwUbBeI5DTl3Om9zw3GN50nm8vIGV+iu3rJzK98j/dhVqFWtVb4FawfqC8dXOq/evgdYkrOldq7G2aO3kOs91h9YT1qeu/6nQpLCi8NWGiA09RcpF64omNnpubC2WKOYX39hkt2nvZtRm7ubBLeZbarZ8LGGXXC41Ka0qfV/GKrv8jek31d982pq4dbDcqnzPNsw23rax7Y7bD1VIV+RXTOzw39FZyagsqXy1M3bnpSqLqr27CLsEu4TVftXdNZo122re1ybXjta51LXXK9VvqZ/bzd49ssdpT9te5b2le9/t4+67ud9zf2eDdkPVAcyBnAMPG8Mb+79lftvcpNBU2vThIO+g8FDwob5m6+bmFqWW8la4VdA6fTjm8NXv3L7rbjNs299Oby89Ao4Ijjz+Pu77saO+R3uPMY+1/aD1Q30HtaOkE+pc2TnTldwl7I7qHj7uc7y3x66n40ejHw+eUDtRd1LmZPkpwqmiU59O55+ePZN55unZpLMTvbG9d85FnrveF9Q3eN73/MULHhfO9Tv3n75of/HEJdtLxy8zL3ddsbrSOWA50PGT5U8dg1aDnUPWQ91Xba72DC8ePjXiOHL2mtu1C9e9r18ZXTI6PBY2dvNGzA3hTfbNR7fSbj2/nXN7/s66u+i7Jfek7lXdV7rf8LPez+1CK+HJcbfxgQchD+5MsCae/JL1y/vJoofkh1VTqlPNj8wenZj2mL76eOnjySeZT+afFv8q/Wv9M91nP/zm9NvATOTM5HP+808vyl7Kvzz4yuJV72zg7P3X6a/n50reyL859Jb5tv9dxLup+dz32PfVH/Q+9Hz0/Xj3U/qnT/8CWOPhMQplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0Rpc3BsYXlEb2NUaXRsZSBmYWxzZQovTm9uRnVsbFNjcmVlbkJlaGF2aW9yL1VzZU5vbmUKL0ZpdFdpbmRvdyBmYWxzZQovQ2VudGVyV2luZG93IGZhbHNlCi9IaWRlVG9vbGJhciBmYWxzZQovSGlkZVdpbmRvd1VJIGZhbHNlCi9IaWRlTWVudWJhciBmYWxzZQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNSAwIG9iago8PAovQ29udGVudHNbOCAwIFIgOSAwIFJdCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMKPDwKL1Byb2NTZXRbL1BERi9UZXh0L0ltYWdlQ10KL1hPYmplY3QKPDwKL0hpUVBkZl9tZWlnbmhvZ21la2FrbWtkYmRwbGVnZnBrZ2NrbmRpbiA2IDAgUgovSGlRUGRmX2Frb25haGxjcGVkaGttcHBwZGJwcGZoZ2hrY2ZraWdmIDcgMCBSCj4+Cj4+Ci9NZWRpYUJveFswIDAgNTk1IDg0Ml0KL1BhcmVudCAyIDAgUgovVHlwZS9QYWdlCi9Hcm91cAo8PAovQ1MvRGV2aWNlUkdCCi9TL1RyYW5zcGFyZW5jeQovSSBmYWxzZQovSyBmYWxzZQo+Pgo+PgplbmRvYmoKNiAwIG9iago8PAovUmVzb3VyY2VzCjw8Ci9Qcm9jU2V0Wy9QREYvVGV4dC9JbWFnZUNdCi9Gb250Cjw8Ci9KU1pEVkMrVGltZXNOZXdSb21hblBTLUl0YWxpY01UIDE3IDAgUgo+Pgo+PgovQkJveFswIDAgNTY1IDEzLjgwNV0KL1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybQovTGVuZ3RoIDEyNAovRm9ybVR5cGUgMQovVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Ci9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUKL05hbWUvSGlRUGRmX21laWduaG9nbWVrYWtta2RiZHBsZWdmcGtnY2tuZGluCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nBXNTQrCMBAG0P13itmLcSYxTQVx4c9CQVE7VHBX2igVW2kVvL6Vd4CHDkxMPvEkzqTsOaE+4oIW3WCpmOyy6zpfjbRu4vsQv+dXU7THbLz9FM+63CuJJb3BcjB+mpIzIhLYkVYQYmMD+9kw9HfMF6QPbBSnvx8yWh19CmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKNyAwIG9iago8PAovUmVzb3VyY2VzCjw8Ci9Qcm9jU2V0Wy9QREYvVGV4dC9JbWFnZUNdCi9Gb250Cjw8Ci9JRENWRVMrQXJpYWwtQm9sZE1UIDExIDAgUgovSURDVkVTK0FyaWFsTVQgMTIgMCBSCj4+Cj4+Ci9CQm94WzAgMCA4MDAgMTA3OV0KL1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybQovTGVuZ3RoIDU5MjIKL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEKL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdAovRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCi9OYW1lL0hpUVBkZl9ha29uYWhsY3BlZGhrbXBwcGRicHBmaGdoa2Nma2lnZgo+PgpzdHJlYW0KeF7tXV1zFEeWrQ3tEw7CZhEYsB3RD8K2sICs76yJ4GFnhWE8iG8hiICH3Z1l2Y1mNsY/Gc/8ip3xTGZWdeXJ7puVWbdaoqOD8UhqHaRbJ8/9yMxbWS1xS+j/zRZfpVi8SkXddC9//q/ZyeyP58/N/qQ+iH9/f/4c+XtzxIUFCejd+XMn589110gXppa+/vzfyqC9zAJWl6+bbBWfIy4tKP2Q+9uK1NsbitLsyflzf1qlvfiqadXVwkRVAK2qWUbnDpojKodRsDCCWC6Wrb73M+jRzKLWAAnC77NYgVp5ugzOEYznxFOK6cIMUTmM8ohxxAK3kL5an1jNAnbE6tG5X0I5iKKFbSDWK468eoehUdq1YgjcIk5W6LTPIseDqZtctGPlIOqY2BJuve4Otd5vjlnaxWII3DJaoLdc4K4nJVzO62AZgNHIu6miBcMsrWDxAjZolCecNSBh/WX9KfFi1ssjiKGFdzyP4soQPIoLQ1o09CgNM9nB8CDcQDYMbjo5xDDKDDUYWrN45crWw65sbn7IAIxGRrCrapJdVZPsAK4dWAZgJju2drUDywDMZFf2BdNhVzYpZRjg2oFFAGay22zPpiXJLi1JdgDXDiwDMJPdhns2XzGgHVtQZi3q+C8fRpnENtuptpIjuZx0aU561FqgUSaxjfUnTzFnphXD6FqJeSo6wjVJgkZ51OzVsoJcJVl47sICYRmCJ66SrN33Ayx6OG8sbG3QKJrgUaPWvc6ILTqKGE8ztkeRBRjxwMVkj46QDX1Ee26dsvWF3pWtdITwqCkDMBrZGnZWfCRn3YdmPa4Ww+i2EQPNqwXu+rOH5wNulgEYjbzjyIbkrEBo1iOmGEaZxD7JxiIGQ+sXXK5s7k7To6YMwGhkBDu7O5vgVDDigc9au3Ehx9SODjnPqD0anVLQWQOom417Z0/CyobJmo0h5iSvGEaZxCAcmsoyg5jq4flABMoAjEa2hp0VH8lZ96FZj6vFMLptxFDzxY5yyZ+w0fS6WYZgMPJuqmzhYGtKUiIa5QkHBkA38Cjuzy06hhhPM75HS4RlCOaxY8qG6SECKI+YHVpekLFm4fmAmnIYdoxsDbtefIdc7z7HrMfVYhDdOmKoOZmkFp4PuFmGYF4uwPCoJHXMesQUAZRH7JNsLGIwtGpRzV3ZKqfIe9SUARiNjGBnNyQTnIpGPPBZazcq5JjapXXWGwbtPMP2iIRGPDBTu3LFwHuvXQ8LsEGjPGp0rtJmaQqnlKvWAIabLRcYKLwiwgw1JjF61iRRJjHMInptVGHk+BJXhmDeTA/DI5cgaNYjpgigPGKfZGMRg6FJ8kC4hecDasoAjEZGsIMKz3cqGvHAZ63dqJBjakeHnGfUHo1OKeisAdTNxj2OmJcNkzUbRYyel0iUScyGQyHIRLDwfCAC5TDsGNkadr34DrnefY5Zj6vFILp1xEDzjCxsFp4PuFkGYDSyNeys+EjOOhXNelwthtFtI4aak1tSC88H3CxDMG85TssWDraMeg7Nh/KEAwPUFsYZMaBjiPE043uUfCjUC/PYMWUjC6wH5RGDoRXkc6wWng+oKQMwGtkadlZ8JGfdh2Y9rhbD6LYRQ83pylbQlc11swzBU2sbkgPZyNnKEVMEUB6xT7KxiMHQ6Kf9CvppvyU1ZQBmPu9nt78TnIpGPPBZazcq5Jja0SHnGbVHo1MKOmuAfCzXGTEvGyZrNooYudigUSYxCAf6ieHCffTRE4EyAE9+jHMT2VnxyadfHbMeV4thdNuIoeaL6y75M7WGvW6WIRiMvJsqWzjY8J2BrA0aZQoHBkA38CiM2KKjiPE0Y3sUWYARDywne3SEbORTcz6URwyG1ixG7MrWOEJ41JQBGI1sDTsrPpKz7kOzHleLYXTbiFnNy/6Nyxx/Wng+4GY5DDtG3jFkc8j1AjlmPWKKQZRL7JNsLGIwtHTxypWth+cDasoAjEZGsLMbkglOhV0NDZ+1diNDjqkdHXKeUXs0OqWgswZQN5sNOGJeNkzWbAQxN3nFMMokBuGQk/dwLTwfiEAZgNHI1rCz4iM56z4063G1GEa3jRhqTh6StfB8wM0yBE88tDgy2HKqP+9DecKBAepQtjNiQMcQ42nG9yh5H8gL89gxZaNuc/tQHjEYWkneKrXwfEBNGYDRyNaws+IjOes+NOtxtRhGt40Yak5XtpKubK6bZQieWtuQHMhGzlaOmCKA8oh9ko1FDIZWk3fVLDwfUFMG4Jp3cwj2KXynohEPfNbajQq5euKNNUc6z6g9Gp1S0FkDqJuNexwxLxsmazaKGLnYoFEmMQiH/g8JuKHWOPfJPBEoAzAa2Rp2VnwkZ92HZj2uFsPothFDzcljZBaeD7hZhmDeoShatnCw9e8+6kpEozzhwAB1kMwZMaBjiPE043s0RViGYB47pmzUbW4fyiNmh1ali+s6sll4PqCmHIYdI1vDrhffIde7zzHrcbUYRLeOGGpOVjYLzwfcLEPwxNrmkAPZqNnKFVMEUB6xT7KxiMHQeluubD08H1BTBmA0MoKd3ZBMcCoa8cBnrd2okGNqR4ecZ9QejU4p6KwB1M3GPY6Ylw2TNRtFjFpseFAmMQiHYvHKDbUeng9EoAzAaITJbnHlJXaNNcxnB0becZyK5Kz70KzH1WIYnU4MfArEwBtMYpP9ST/MX9EP8y8FoQzAzGfSoVa5z8uT7ACm35/HBzPZ8bUje6Y+mMnOvteNwy6tc8owwPT78/hgJrsN92y5YsA4ljJrUfLNgzwok9hmO9VWIyRn65nz7gu29iEqhlEmsY31J1MxnC3EMLpWYp6qhDDVnfehPGr2anXmcGtW4LkDC2dlIgNwxmNXydXrvR+gYWFwHxrxwLx1CFhA7ar+Ty85wwZ4HLvsrD1Lrjp8MJNdlRe9YfAsigRO8WkHRjww07PWguPZ/siO61kLj2PH1W6j464SaW8YPQsioWc92oERD8z0rLXgaCeyFXjuwOPYcbXb6Lgr+7fNdz0LIqFnae3QiAfmeRYsoHZlRToF4HHsmNptdtyl/e85nkWRwCke7dCIB+Z5FiygdmlWr8BzBx7Hjqndhsdd3tsFx6JG4BOPdGCDRnlutQacjCCrVOUpacMoU7PNjrd+ye8WYXLJQ8sGFmiU509rAFXLyTTIySwIEWMqtrGBxlQM3EM7bbJiuL4nj7pbeD6wpZAhmHeinJYtvLEh31zIh/KEAwPUKXxnxICOIcbTjO9R8lilF+axY8qG6SECKI8YDK1YjNiVrXCE8KgpAzAaYbKjM6HwZMI4dlNzAclZ9zlNSdrVYhidTgx8CsQw8XjEeP6ELRq+fQPs8/ApeYCdd2OyRjww8y0cYJvhsLN7FYedhR0a1ogH5rL7pB2fnW364Bs5QOfIeejbwg4Na8QDT34zB4cdlDP6zTkcGljOaJjJDrZojmebVdjVDt9eBY14YJ5nYbuB2sGeBYcNMIoERjzwdO2QHeyR0TDASAOMeGAmO7u8d5KioMxWnroxjDKJbbZT7SyI5HLSpTnpUZhHSZRJbGP9SStWV6Q7ESY3yR50IrXGfVpArsBzF4ZyBTZolHcYzh5MSOk34kqxZiIsLIxGPDCv8IKF2nFqswK77GpwHxrxwDy3lv005GhnT4Y4w0YYREIjHpinHVhA7YAGDhthEAmNeGCedmlJxp19qMMZNsIgEhrxwDztwAJqBzRw2AiDSGjEA/O060ulI13a/51oZ9QIY27mAZQnnDWAugEHHDLCmJh5AOWp1pdKN1mLFXTuoKAOWKBRnmbWgJOnxQrqEENtwAKN8hTDs2xk9fUdrMVjP2jEA09nR/biKueP2dFHHcPH9Zh/zw4PtJHV1xk2wlgqwIgH5mmHFkA7pAHD9hx1DJ/ZY2oHB9uwiMDJQSwiAINGYINGecKBAdANOcCQPWcdQ+f2mKr16b6UrNSIAaUKhg/laQYGnDylxkufdAQLNMpTDDtB0FvF9hXWBIChMYlGPDCvv4oWFldeYldYw76eW7DZNfUt05eko5WjFKL7vOtsSzuq0aJR4oQ2zkzFqLByW1yOZgBjWHmCkA5ZJjvUDWigcJ7mZbDxy9XOl6nlCjx34Y+aqeUKvMTuLDIVO3uoHXTHUTuAQSQ04oF52qEF1A5ooHZ0Sz/cvGRqh9140C58a9AJMBmEedqhBdAOacCwPS398A0HpnbYGgXtsP8Mw0YYREIjHpinHVoA7ZAGDNvTNA93f5naEfPoe7cHDaNG2JkTAihPOGImXaIGQ/Z0zUMdYKZqnjUJOTUC+tHWJOSsSPfMJ6xJ1P9/+/z8udu/O/y3F3ef/fCvP//Pv89v/vb/5n84ej7r36v1+VsV5GYLMktFri8xe/6H4UHdFLfStKyy2fP/VBf7PkmT198nVXI7kcmfk+v6mzTZS3aSW0mW5MlBcjPZ25/Nnv+v+uG7io8iF0NQAEEz3FnTFJH0slSUzYJeqRnlitx1RfFAsdLcflBwo17VivitdfEzvYMgP0UvS2WvXpY8S/6aPEieJC+Sh+rrjvr6Mrmnvr40Gh4mx8mj5GnyKvkxebkenuZZpwieomiqesHzjpZRKAlvKhE/KBdnilxqvvuz+nqgyGbJd+p79WO3DfM9pfFtBWqdv41nvky6MtPXrCmLONZZUWbFgnWT3Ff6PUh+pz5+VB/HSs8nRuU7iqHWWGv7F4U+3F+LtlkTyTIv0z5EtZdP1McL8/nYRMKhYve0j43D5Bv1/eXkYnItuZJ8rf77PNmZyLjtUsRTTrNS/1xL+YZybNn5X4vZaL//TXn65kRWVZ2OYpWJOuuT6boS72lytOTeX4ycWsBdJdyVfXYodj4WZRy1PM2sjy21N4rMPeXTIxWbP6nv9ev7Kr91XC6I3km+SL5S3r6U/Iv6uKj++3oqbWluFMbQLoX1856idKKIvTIkd1RAakUfJ3fVd9/sj3d1irzMLDSTdR1DTNX1PBOlXDA7MFG3p2rOnvG1/n5ntUypb3f6SnVDfTuVdGniU5qFYRTpXFS9nLmphwdtmay6upmrTGonpjsMchmSa0xoyjwqQrV7p16wlUGmUdlqVg5VXlk1nqpap/Pgnpnhnpgqfbg/KtIdOu0kIUX0QqZKBTinNM5xZrKbOrz2Z5NqWm7ivL2/P4uK88pOvKXKtePkwkQK0kRELSOn/rwQVpeudE1k0M42dV3EMpB1uWDwRoXIY1V5jlSA/KInyf21qFFFVsRUT30LLp+ZIn0y2SOm4z2rSxHHISsz2SfOr0qPF6Yu/6hevX47kUpuek2xAaq4NNJGR6a8oxco7ZJl3Z6q2lSODtyi/U1bX16p4P2lXUNNpFKLYpRKeV6XQEUvQx93xe7uZDJlLdrwaeLIZAJC+EgtjE50Uu9PdU4zioRshHXOr8nvk1dTCZTlKAIlLm0eJ5cmXr7dL9d5Gnf1qoar704uIFU56upFA+F4Ta0qr6q15e5EDmkmR5BQU5uo87Kf2vR+fLGE21HbSKkWQX9T2P/rqbeZSK19e8xYatoj++vJhjzSIVmZ57kNh13lkK/3p7qjpZBGr38ErDS0/FJVKr23/2Z/PerHMVmj+nEXXJv6xOq7ipur9MJq6gXbTk7VzgXPw+4WavHd14BGTdNtz4G19h6oiFWZRxI6jZVuPYKCbsYVtpWpZ2k9Pz9Wn09USXqg5HlmPk8Wpt19R9PK299saVWmY3Bs+lRHpq2xHlKVObg2gtRprmi60Mkj9wdZA90oNZkqWSolzKsuqHU4/9o1VO+pz0+7/s9FNeldTq6uh2satRLUeYerrw+qzJZJbea5HTX3lWr2u6G++9bMgmWS/dPr/zDj+aA0VhPhD6aTurOGjl9m/iBgLG9dLiqr8Y22s//6e0P4tmmcHxjVazVf3Dbq7ip1rySX42kuMzT3WWZlE72eWwqCXf6l03ZnGn3ttBR2Alk0n3QjSpqu94fuTkPe3oDobpKYV1q1Rv3QXtcB+jY52J+tIR7LOpJ6JmXdy3YpMneurDFzyridt86cFBo0bua0a8dUvfosuakUrxSiEubtGhIlLdIRNE0sWJbCCCo6WQ/Uq5bvrpLvQrLGOyNdshSR1fs0kiX22huYLFkkdSdZLn+MZBFVHFORpUVO58pilslOJVvaXXg8z7wsoQes3FwberdMSmiK19X335lX7Yx9fX9ikhSyjuN2CkkSfe3NS5KiiqTuJMmXHyFJirg+qrkDUaQ1nSWLGWUNKdF2VIvY7m6eCRt2mSJy3Sh0Te1KLys99eevlF46G66ug15Tj6KX4mK7ndkapdsPJmHbdaue3aYTy+RIb2Y5tMXXPLMWsZ2c0ygasdfewKKRRlJ3isaVj1A0cnuiKF1hmvVM9TJUFtbDr3/2zK5rqh3mzYFiyS11smD7eEmVD/31YrfE14cflHLm9Q1zi/PCGthm7f3waLYCcyVu8l8Dy7w9YxDPUgDL71Qu3eg25yZ99kalNx61q8wDhIpHFcNDN8iKRjRWrmNz+EK3XJ44J4R+n+ijGU9VnrQniR6uqR2T11E7IJ0hTW0L8emmRzqCmZKzylM4bddOrV+pTLhiGhZfmvy4bBrA08llaT6K3EfKhrwZx3KN2UDMs3ls//EU5tnoa3+kedajWGyX1FHs0noUi712XqV5X7ruqKL0rOsYP+oK2NMuqC90U1R30M1MUHfhJJ89CjfpGNyCfxa7PCnrotcuNeX2xJxuuG9G8NKU31fmCJNmfGxG9YsZ2VFXnO8lbVdU//ur7vcOzemNHWe0D7uffbG0/GnPVHxQX4/NaY+/mmqqD7H+ZA6yHo4rBsuKlG2bK1qRvMmLvsZr//zdWWgsjxAXHD+ZEV7Yn+w9Edm7zuq87I8BP0jemNy8b449HBq9ted+MgX22EybiwJ7t4u+B8aX2if3e/4Pumm3HfvC05N8ULRdk+hx5QJWeyfA8F43/R+Z72z+tFPeCOUHlgPd9izM0lnaX41c2l9d49I+iz7knmb2DuSemW731Ba3Paa55qaAeSgmnlpWpWl/3NU2Ba6akqJLxzWzitFJto7z4FmWjaKXpjC3qH1HNwNeN3eHbrYHb3dVcZjOrEuOaGbOemWxgDIn1Cf3BLIisiN2CmuV6GunH7knQByKyOLuOc5GuYi+YBslmYha3OqGoAqv3lN1ct+cAVj/oYhUlpGETuFQRBtAkRTO7lBEu/6IpnU2hyLaMhhNKk3hUMSBOQyrloRTSciRypz+yYw0tvryjzmuro3MhYvI29prLbnVuGs7B+YXDsCNzqXutoh+2uylwtulfbsJaHufeqOzq15/qWZzvdW5Mp19HumyPIVzYfRWR5olsF40H3ebmx2z3Dw26KFZCrdbIr2RuTY41s+nLZibcWMr4BDLq84jvxrG7QbgkSkbJ86W7eIw//3Jnom++5w3Au5vPFIrwEumX/WF4nK5jRPz+kvzpNjX6tWOWVYfmge2HuqCCOMKxeBLhT0xh/fbn7Dbi2fG76+M3/WW96kqLE+6f3+kfvYvbd0z29Sd5IvpChkwQqFcVPYBwPbxNL0V0owe9JGpx/mZ2fa1Y3rZjetu0j5xu5hKHnTq4Whfms7qiZkF9WNvr98qsN0H6r3LkUmSlwa7b3bqepp80u8V98wEfqiSSSdKu4c/6Igdmsu9mSxWE7kwzLLcPlTTbnzbJ4snbmKz9tGIWBq5KIp+b14qCm0gXlefH3UO0huH1k17E6m1689YakJkNpreGFoPTc1ra8TUY9Gdv+rYg4Npmg7vTn9jdlt1eyxvx5ykb9ftK2cJbUf+8+kbsnYAdWTPIs3Lqt+P6ONQ7Sj0zdqq24vsmmK2juZ20Z6Cq2MlFjk8zHTH3Kgw26LrE3m0T91mIpJGJsDTXxhv7ald9D+TpVR//AM6ad6WCmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKOCAwIG9iago8PAovTGVuZ3RoIDEzNgovRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp4Xk2MvRKCMBCE+8zkHe4J4hGTA3sLS6ksHUwIYSJw+v6FYfiRrb6Z3W8Lq3AO7GBpo6rQK31beMAoBXyk2Idk1MWSNgejpGyYczUbUiwKqhJJW8yAy+oAa7V9/k8RwA3ZhtOtr+8+PJs0jU18O259TAMz+xdziF1MLqS+C3CdpKil+AEyQi+gCmVuZHN0cmVhbQplbmRvYmoKOSAwIG9iago8PAovTGVuZ3RoIDEyMQovRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN ", 
    "application/pdf"), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("dokumentId", "filename", "lenght", "content", "contentType"
    ))))
```

how to generate a pdf (or text) file from this binary file?

Comment: Have you tried the package base64?

Comment: I have tried it and have found the solution. Thanks.